# error in executing loadui test in Linux: "loadUI-cmd.sh: ...syntax error near unexpected token `in"

Tags: linux, shell

This is my shell command line in linux:

```
.../loadUI-cmd.sh -J-Djava.awt.headless=true -p /.../loadui_basicPTproject.xml -r /.../PT_reports -F PDF
```

and this is output (error):

```
: command not found/SmartBear/LoadUI-2.6.8/loadUI-cmd.sh: line 10:
: command not found/SmartBear/LoadUI-2.6.8/loadUI-cmd.sh: line 12:
: command not found/SmartBear/LoadUI-2.6.8/loadUI-cmd.sh: line 14:
'home/bbiixli/tools/SmartBear/LoadUI-2.6.8/loadUI-cmd.sh: line 15: syntax error near unexpected     token `in
'home/bbiixli/tools/SmartBear/LoadUI-2.6.8/loadUI-cmd.sh: line 15: `case "`uname`" in
```

Note: loadUI-cmd.sh script is "come with the product". The script content is below (the top 2 lines added by me for avoid running the script with unix format error.

```
### the below line was added for linux env 052114
:set fileformat=unix
###!/bin/sh
### ====================================================================== ###
##                                                                          ##
##  loadUI Agent Bootstrap Script                                          ##
##                                                                          ##
### ====================================================================== ###
### $Id$ ###

DIRNAME=`dirname $0`

# OS specific support (must be 'true' or 'false').
cygwin=false;
case "`uname`" in
    CYGWIN*)
        cygwin=true
        ;;
esac

# Setup LOADUI_HOME
if [ "x$LOADUI_HOME" = "x" ]
then
    # get the full path (without any relative bits)
    LOADUI_HOME=`cd $DIRNAME/; pwd`
fi
export LOADUI_HOME

LOADUI_CLASSPATH="$LOADUI_HOME:$LOADUI_HOME/lib/*"

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin
then
    LOADUI_HOME=`cygpath --path -w "$LOADUI_HOME"`
    LOADUI_CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path -w "$LOADUI_CLASSPATH"`
fi

JAVA="jre/bin/java"

if [ ! -f "$JAVA" ]; then
  JAVA="java"
fi

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms128m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m"

$JAVA $JAVA_OPTS -cp "$LOADUI_CLASSPATH" com.javafx.main.Main --cmd=true --nofx=true -nofx -         Dlog4j.configuration=log4j_headless.xml "$@"
```

Anyone can Help me on this problem?

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: What is `:set fileformat=unix` doing there? Make sure the very first line of the script is `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: @Janos, `:set fileformat=unix` avoids error  `: /path/to/scriptfile:/bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.` (http://lanvu.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/linux-shell-scripting-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory/) However, either `:set fileformat=unix` or `#!/bin/sh` got the same error as my previous post.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your file has DOS style line ending characters. Fix that using the `dos2unix` command if your system has it. If you don't have it, you can do like this:

```
tr -d '\r' < script.sh > fixed.sh
mv fixed.sh script.sh
chmod +x script.sh
```

After this, change the first line to:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

Then it should work.

Comment: yes it eliminated the errors in my 1st post. Now get different error `JavaFX 2.1.0 is required to view this content but JavaFX. Get the JavaFX runtime from java.com/javafx and run the installer. Then restart the application` if I click `Install Now` the output: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Desktop API is not supported on the current platform
        at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop(Desktop.java:144)...`        Neither `jre bundled with LoadUI` nor `jre1.7.0_51` works. Reference (http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=19033)

Comment: Now that's an entirely different problem, and if you cannot solve it it's better to ask on http://superuser.com/ I think, or if you're on Ubuntu then on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: agree. Thanks much for the nice help and reference. -larry